# How to change log.info/error message's font color in Jmeter's JSR223?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I'm trying to find a way to change log.info/error message's font color so that it would be easier for me to read messages in Jmeter's JSR223 Log section

any advice ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As per current version ([JMeter 4.0](https://dzone.com/articles/whats-new-in-jmeter-40)) I don't think it is possible. You can use [Groovy Coloriser](http://Colorizer) library if you want, however it will only work for `println` statements, not for JMeter's `log.error`

The only way you can filter out the log output to errors only is configuring [JMeter logging subsystem](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) to display **only** messages of ERROR level (or above). You can do this in at least 2 ways:

- Locate `<Root level="info">` line in *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) and change `info` to `error`. JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up
- Or you can simply run JMeter like `jmeter -LERROR`

In both cases you will not be seeing all these `INFO` and/or `WARN` messages anymore, you will see only `ERROR` and above.

More information:

- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)